# How to open a jdialog from a jframe

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

JFrame button to open the jdialog:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
```

JDialog method that opens the dialog:

```
        public void run() {
            AddClient dialog = new AddClient(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
            dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            dialog.setVisible(true);
```

My JDialog class is named AddClient, my JFrame class is named MainWindow. The package these are in is named my.javaapp

How would i go onto doing this? I'm pretty new to java, was using python up until this point and dove head in into java swing gui builder with netbeans, i'm planning on watching tutorials and reading through the java documentation to learn more about java, but i would like to start by being able to open this jdialog.

*Before asking this question i searched a lot, and i read other questions that had been asked to solve more or less this same problem, i still couldn't solve mine though so i'm asking.*

**Solution:**

Delete the main function from the class the gui you want to pop up is on e.g

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the dialog */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            NewJDialog1 dialog = new NewJDialog1(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
            dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Before deleting though, copy this line:

```
NewJDialog1 dialog = new NewJDialog1(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
```

Right click the button you want to pop this window up after pressing, events > action > action performed. Paste it there like this:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

NewJDialog1 dialog = new NewJDialog1(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true); 

dialog.setVisible(true);

}
```

Remember to add the last line, that's what shows up the dialog.

Comment: *"dove head in into java swing gui builder with netbeans"*  That's where 'all hope was lost'.  Dump the automagic IDE for a while and learn how to code 1) Java and 2) GUIs.

Comment: *"i read other questions that had been asked to solve more or less this same problem"*  What other questions (link to three that were closest)?  Why did they not help?

Comment: I knew i would get that first comment as an answer, haha, you're right. I'll get down to it,  I just wanted to start learning from the point i wanted and not from the very beggining, i just wanted to go on learning what i needed from there.. I'll still do it.. I'll code the backend process for that dialog and when its done ill know more about java so ill come back to opening the dialog from that mainwindow.. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: i'll edit this question and explain the solution once i learn how to do it and why i couldn't get it to work before so that this question does not goes to waste..

Answer (score 2):

The constructor on JDialog accept parent object. But you use new JFrame object. This is error (logical error).

```
AddClient dialog = new AddClient(MainWindow.this);
```

If you want modal dialog, call

```
dialog.setModal(true);
```

And set default close operation.

```
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Use of thread is unnecessary.

Ps: sorry for bad English

**Edit:**
Here is simple example with exit code in dialog

```
public class AddClient extends JDialog {
    public static final int ID_OK = 1;
    public static final int ID_CANCEL = 0;

    private int exitCode = ID_CANCEL;

    public AddClient(Frame owner) {
        super(owner);
        createGUI();
    }

    public AddClient(Dialog owner) {
        super(owner);
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        setTitle(getClass().getSimpleName());

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
    }

    public int doModal() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setModal(true);
        setVisible(true);

        return exitCode;
    }
}
```

And MainWindow

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    public MainWindow() throws HeadlessException {
        super();
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle(getClass().getSimpleName());

        JButton addClientButton = new JButton("Add client");
        addClientButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AddClient dialog = new AddClient(MainWindow.this);
                        if(dialog.doModal() == AddClient.ID_OK) {

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        toolBar.add(addClientButton);

        add(toolBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have it enclosed with Thread, you need to call start() on this thread,
if you have Runnable you need to enclose it by Thread class, and then call start().

On Runnable and Thread, you can also call run(), but it will run in current Thread.

Is this your case, because I see part of run()  method in your code?